# Python web scraping gives wrong source code

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

I want to extract some data from Amazon(link in the following code)

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
url="http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_11?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%2144258011%2Cn%3A2205237011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A2656020011%2Cn%3A173507&bbn=2205237011&sort=titlerank&ie=UTF8&qid=1393984161&rnid=1000"
webpage=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
doc=open("test.html","w")
doc.write(webpage)
doc.close()
```

When I open the test.html, the content of my page is different from the website in the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page involves javascript execution.

`urllib2.urlopen(..).read()` simply read the url content. So they are different.

To get same content, you need to use library that can handle javascript.

For example, following code uses [`selenium`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_11?...161&rnid=1000'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete falsetru's answer:

another solution is to use [python-ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/). It is based on Qt. It's much heavier to install, so I advice Selenium too.

Using Firefox will open it up on script execution. To not have it on your way, use PhantomJS:

```
apt-get install nodejs  # you get npm, the Node Package Manager
npm install -g phantomjs  # install globally
[…]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```